# C++ default initialization in constructor of an inherited reference member

Tags: c++, inheritance, reference, constructor, initialization

I have a base class that updates an extern reference, and I want to build an inherited class that would embed this reference as a member. A kind of default initialization of the reference.

I came up with the following solution:

```
#include<iostream>

class Statefull
{
public:
    Statefull( int& ref ) : _base_ref(ref) {}
    int& _base_ref;
    // update the extern variable
    void work() { std::cout << ++_base_ref << std::endl; }
};

class Stateless : public Statefull
{
public:
    // use a temporary allocation
    Stateless( int* p = new int() ) :
        // we cannot initialize local members before base class:
        // _dummy(), Statefull(_dummy)
        // thus, initialize the base class on a ref to the temporary variable
        Statefull(*p),
        _tmp(p),
        _dummy()
    {
        // redirect the ref toward the local member
        this->_base_ref = _dummy;
    }
    int* _tmp;
    int _dummy;
    // do not forget to delete the temporary
    ~Stateless() { delete _tmp; }
};

int main()
{
    int i = 0;
    Statefull full(i);
    full.work();

    Stateless less;
    less.work();
}
```

But the need of a temporary allocation in a default argument of the constructor seems quite ugly. Is there a more elegant way to achieve this kind of default initialization while *keeping a reference* in the base class constructor?

Comment: You don't _redirect_ the reference. You just assigned the variable, referenced by _base_ref, a value from dummy. You cannot redirect references, only initialize them.

Comment: Does the inheritance hierarchy make sense? I'd expect either `Stateless` to be the base class, or a third class as the common base.

Comment: @SimonRichter the problem would be the declaration of `_ref_base`, in `Stateless` it is not supposed to be a reference, in `Statefull`, it is. If I do not want to re-implement `work`, it would necessitate to declare `_ref_base` as a template in the base class, which I prefer to avoid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this might work:

```
StateLess(): Statefull(*new int) {}
~StateLess() { delete &_base_ref; }
```

You can't do without temporaries, but they don't have to be in the classes definitions.

Answer (score 4):

Well, the `Stateless` class is violating the rule of three. But I'll assume that's because this is just sample code to exhibit the real problem.

Now, to actually address the problem: it's perfectly valid to bind a reference to an uninitialized variable, as long as its value is not used before initialization actually happens.

```
Stateless() : Statefull(_dummy), _dummy() {}
```

The present solution works, but it seems there's some misunderstanding about *why* it works.

```
    // redirect the ref toward the local member
    this->_base_ref = _dummy;
```

You cannot "redirect" references. You can only bind a reference once: upon initialization. Assigning to a reference assigns to the object it refers to. In this case, `this->_base_ref = _dummy` *is exactly the same as* `*_tmp = _dummy` : it assigns the value of `_dummy` to `*_tmp`. `_base_ref`, however, still refers to `*_tmp` (you can test this with `assert(&_base_ref == tmp)`).

Comment: "as long as its value is not used before initialization actually happens"

Indeed. And this would be quite annoying in my real-world example…

Answer (score 0):

Everything can be solved using some more classes

```
class StateForStateful
{
protected:
    int state;
};

class Stateless: private StateForStateful, public Stateful // order is important
{
public:
     Stateless():Stateful(this->state) {}
};
```